# 'Publish' ribbon tab missing on Web Part Page

Tags: ribbon

In a SharePoint 2013 environment, I have a 'Site Pages' library with 2 content types: `Wiki Page` and `Web Part Page`. I have enabled **minor versioning** in the library. When I open a `Wiki Page`, there's a new **`Publish`** tab in the ribbon, allowing the users to directly publish a major version when they're done editing. However, this tab is missing on the `Web Part Pages`.
Is this a bug? Is there a way to add it to the `Web Part Pages` as well?

I've found the definition of the tab in the `\15\TEMPLATE\GLOBAL\XML\CMDUI.XML` file - it might be possible to extract the definition into a custom action but it seems like an overkill to me.

Similar issues are being described [here](http://www.topsharepoint.com/missing-publish-tab-on-custom-publishing-pages) and [here](http://www.savtechsol.com/Education/BeckysBlog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=130) but none of these apply to my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is because you cannot edit the layout of a webpart page, only add content. You can access the publishing of a webpart page by selecting the checkbox next to it in the Site Pages library and then clicking the publish button on the Documents ribbon.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense from the technical perspective but one might have a hard time explaining it to the business users. I'm aware of the possibility to publish a `Web Part Page` from the containing library, I was just looking for a way to make it work the same way it does for the `Wiki Pages`. But thank you anyway! :)